# Bitbucket dependencies not being downloaded in maven project

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket-api

I am trying to write a BitBucket pull request listener. But the jars related to it is not getting downloaded when I try to create a maven project.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.bitbucket.server    /bitbucket-api -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.bitbucket.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>bitbucket-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-m7</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.bitbucket.server:bitbucket-api:jar:4.0.0-m7 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.470 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-05T13:31:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bitbucketsniffer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bitbucketsniffer:bitbucketsniffer:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.atlassian.bitbucket.server:bitbucket-api:jar:4.0.0-m7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Is there a way to manually install the jars as we do with oracle dependency jar, if yes then will this work if I try to create an executable jar of this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the repository as well.

So put this into your pom.xml file before `<dependencies>`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

mvnrepository.com is just a search engine for various libraries. It usually gives you a link in a note when you need to include a repository.

Example:[image: mvnrepository.com different repository example]

Comment: There are some compile dependencies for this, but when I checked the /repositories it shows analytics-api version as 3.69.2. But the required one is 4.0.0, how do I get this version if 'analytics-api' even the maven repository does not have that.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I had to use `<url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-atlassian-external/</url>` instead (even though mvnrepository still showed the original url mentioned in this answer)

Answer (score 1):

I spent more than a day to fix this and this worked for me.

There was following errors while creating new bitbucket plugin project through command: `atlas-create-bitbucket-plugin-module`

**ERROR:** Unable to resolve following dependencies in maven POP.xml:

com.atlassian.bitbucket.server
> bitbucket-api

com.atlassian.bitbucket.server
> bitbucket-spi

**SOLUTION:**

Added this segment to POM.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```